# re module doesn't save the whole text into txt file

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```py
import re

file_name = input("Please input txt directory for your file: ")
#file_name2 = input("Please input txt directory for your file: ")

with open(file_name, 'r') as lol:
    for txt_file in lol:
        x = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', txt_file)
        print(x)
```

It's going to print text without special characters. However, I need to save the printed text to a file. When I do so, it saves only the single line from txt file instead of the whole txt.

```py
import re

file_name = input("Please input txt directory for your file: ")
#file_name2 = input("Please input txt directory for your file: ")

with open(file_name, 'r') as lol:
    for txt_file in lol:
        x = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', txt_file)
        
with open(file_name2, 'w') as p:
    p.write(x)
    p.close()
```

Comment: You're writing `p` after the loop ends. Why did you expect there to be multiple lines written if you only call write function once and immediately close the file? It has nothing to do with the `re` module

Comment: If you simply want to output data to a file, `python app.py > output.txt` from the terminal would do that with the working code

Comment: `x` in your code is only ONE line - you just store the _last read `x`_ into your file. Write inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes aren't the same; you're not writing within the loop anymore.

Did you know you can open multiple files at once?

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as lol, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for txt_file in lol:
        x = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', txt_file)
        f_out.write(x)
        f_out.write('\n')
```